# Path tracing best materials to learn

Tags: pathtracing

i want some of your advices. To begin with i ve never studied computer graphics and i want to do a project with Path tracing which i didnt find the right materials to begin with. Is it recomeneded to start directly learn Path tracing or i have to learn something before. and i wish if someone can give some online examples and some materials

Comment: Look at samples online, find youtube videos that talk about the code behind them, etc.

Comment: http://in1weekend.blogspot.com/2016/01/ray-tracing-in-one-weekend.html?m=1